# Param tag giving null value

Tags: jsp, struts2

`param` tag giving `null` value when i used

```java
System.out.println("Before"+request.getParameter("imeino"));
```

```jsp
<% session.setAttribute("imeino1", request.getParameter("imeino1"));
    System.out.print("BBBBB^^@@"+session.getAttribute("imeino"));
%>
<div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
</div>
<div class="grid" align="center" style="margin-top: 30px">
<ws:url id="remoteurl" action='userimageGrid' escapeAmp="false"> 
    <ws:param name="imeino" value="66666666666"></ws:param>
</ws:url>
```

Comment: Did you use a parameter to the action?

Comment: @RomanC    I have used in struts.xml ==> <action name="userimageGrid" method="userimageGrid" class="com.strutsProject.action.MobileUserAction">
        <param name="imeino">${imeino}</param>
        <result name="json" type="json"></result>
        </action>

Comment: @RomanC when i used above code it giving  value (imeino) when i used System.out.println("Before"+request.getParameter("imeino"));

Comment: @RomanC actual value is  (66666666666)

Comment: It is not null value. And you are using wrong parameter value of the action.

Comment: @RomanC sir help me , how i can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are getting lost when you use `redirect` or `redirectAction` result type. To retain request parameters you should use `dispatcher` result type. This is default result type, and it will be used if you miss `type` attribute of the `<result`  tag, like this:

```xml
<result>/ThankYou.jsp</result>
```

Why `<s:param>` tag giving `null` value. Because the value is converted by OGNL to integer value before adding it to the URL and it throws `NumberFormatException` because no such integer can exist. The value exceeds the maximum in Java for integer value. You should use string value in `<s:param>` tag, like this:

```xml
<s:url var="remoteurl" action='userimageGrid' escapeAmp="false"> 
    <s:param name="imeino" value="'66666666666'"/>
</s:url> 
<s:a href="%{#remoteurl}">Call</s:a>
```

Comment: sir still giving null value

Comment: it should pass with the request, try the link above